# Should we clean up the 12.04 closed questions?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

I've noticed that a bunch of closed questions on [12.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/12.04) are clogging up the search column on the related questions for each question, and also are generally all alpha/beta stuff anyway.

Should we make a conscious effort to remove these before 12.04 is released so not to clog up the new incoming questions?

Yes I mean deletion, here's a list:

- https://askubuntu.com/search?q=%5B12.04%5D+closed%3A1&submit=search

Comment: Can you define "clean up" please, if you're asking for deletion then we need to tread very, very carefully.

Comment: Do we? An unanswered closed non-duplicate post is more harmful than a deleted one IMO

Comment: @Oli Deletion in general is a touchy subject. With this, I don't think it'll be that big of an issue, but we still need to tread carefully. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Delete them, delete them all! (most of them at least)!

Here is also something nice:

- [[12.04] Closed Alpha Beta questions](https://askubuntu.com/search?q=%5B12.04%5D+closed%3A1+beta+alpha&submit=search)
- [[11.10] Closed Alpha Beta questions](https://askubuntu.com/search?q=%5B11.10%5D+closed%3A1+beta+alpha&submit=search)
- [[11.04] Closed Alpha Beta questions](https://askubuntu.com/search?q=%5B11.04%5D+closed%3A1+beta+alpha&submit=search)

Why are these even here? You cant even put your system back to the state of those question much even answer most of them! Should those not *vanish*?

Not going on a rampage, we could check those, one by one and make them go away :/

Deleting is a *subjective* issue only if the questions have been considered useful or have valid answers in them. Those have no value, no content and wont, **ever**, help anyone since they are not even linking to possible solutions. They are closed and a dupe of a general *what to do if I have a issue with beta, alpha* answer.

Comment: +1 for the excellent queries ... and I'll look forward to deleting these if they havent already been done!

Comment: Replacing "alpha" with "beta" also yields results.

Comment: @JorgeCastro Just drop the tags and use `beta alpha closed:1 answers:0`, it returns 180 hits and `beta alpha closed:1` returns 270 ^^

Answer (score 8):

I'm for this.

In my mind there's nothing touchy or controversial about deleting bad content.

Our reasons for closing Ubuntu+1 are fairly solid: it's a moving target and it makes for bad questions. By release-time the closed questions are rot that only serve to pull in people from search engines, showing them a "This question is closed" banner. How can that ever be good for users (or Ask Ubuntu's public image)?

Duplicates are somewhat different because they forward the user onto the master question (if they don't have +1+ answers). There is an exception to this exception: questions that are marked a duplicate of "how do I file a bug" and the other one occasionally used about +1 questions (I'm too lazy to link) - which should also be burnt. With fire.

And if we make a mistake, we can revert deletions. Nothing we delete here is actually deleted.

Bring the rain.

Comment: OMG, I agree. There are certain issues that just need to be buried. Some ignored as they answer themselves and some flat out deleted. Yup! plus one +1

Answer (score 0):

**My own Report on this topic.**

Yep, I will give you a vote on this one, I see far to many old posts, if we don't delete  the old posts it will start to get confused in the data information given out, with the newer types of alpha/beta etc. and this could end up being bad for Ask-Ubuntu.

If say you are new to Ubuntu and get mixed up with the older knowledge out there.. it could even end up being very damaging to the users computer systems! By reading misleading information with the old Alpha/Beta.

**A could be fix.**

Maybe there should be somewhere and some way that the old posts can be archived and saved if needed, so if someone wanted to find out something about an older system problem etc. 
They could go back to the archive and have a look there for the best answer for there problem.

Comment: We should always be updating answers on the site, this isn't about that though, this is about removing the alpha/beta questions that wouldn't apply to released versions of ubuntu.

Comment: All i was saying and trying to get across is that some people that are new on here or Ubuntu may not even know about alpha/beta and could miss read and preform something wrong with there system via the questions etc. i will now edit my post to make it more clear. Thanks for the information. :)